# How to subscribe/unsubscribe from WebSockets with @preact/signals-react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, preact-signal

I've used React's `useState` and `useEffect` for quite some time. I'm just now experimenting with Signals using @preact/signals-react.  Because state can be managed outside of React, I'm trying to create `StatusSignal.ts` that can be accessed from a variety of React components.

Status is collection of server values that will be updated via WebSockets. My current method of subscribing and unsubscribing from WebSockets is:

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("connect", connection_handler);

  return () => {
    socket.off("connect", connection_handler);
  }
}, [] );
```

If I switch over to Signals, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: You don't show enough for anyone to answer. For that tiny block of code, the answer is how you'd manage web sockets in plain JS, without React. Signals would not be relevant or used in that example.